# What does the last column in this IP table mean?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I ran the following commands I found in a tutorial:

```
$sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -L
```

and got

```
target     prot opt source               destination


ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

The [man page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html) just says that -L "lists the rules in the chain." I understand the first 5 columns—but what about the last? What do these mean?

Comment: Do: `iptables -t nat -L`

Answer (score 0):

The last column contains "options". Not every rule has any.

In this case it means the rule does not affect all packets but only those whose connection (keyword: connection tracking) is in one of the states `RELATED` and `ESTABLISHED`.